How to group by priority in oracle
I'm using a select with two inner join that result 3 rows.
[result](https://i.sstatic.net/6UAN2VBM.png)

However i would like to have only one, the result with the next priority.
PAYMENT("P"), 2
CONFIRM("C"), 1
REVERSE("R"), 3
QUERY("Q"), 5
FALLIDA("F"); 4

1 is more priority, the only one row that i would like is confirm.
Greetings.
I would like to resolve the issue, i tried many ways and i can not resolve the issue.

Please don't link to images. Show the data as formatted text instead. Then, don't tell us you tried something, show us what you tried, so we can comment on that and tell you where your approach is good or not so good.

And if you showed the whole query, we might be able to optimize it to only join the best row right away.

If your statuses have a ranking order, the best idea would be to have a status table containing this order. You could simply join the status and get the order and then fetch the best ranking row.
If you don't want to add such a table to your database, then use ORDER BY with a CASE expression, then FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY.
select *
from mytable
order by case when status = 'C' then 1
              when status = 'P' then 2
              when status = 'R' then 3
              when status = 'F' then 4
              when status = 'Q' then 5
              else 6
          end
fetch first row only;


You can also use an analytic function:
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT x.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                                  DECODE(status,'C',1,
                                                'P',2,
                                                'R',3,
                                                'F',4,
                                                'Q',5)) seq
          FROM mytable x)
 WHERE seq = 1

